# Hi, how I can put the value of variable (i) in brackets?

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have N **input**, each **input** have some **id** wath start with 1 to N,
the input are not includes in **FORM**

With JS function I want to display the id of **checked input**
I try to do this like in example

```
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
{   if (document.getElementById('i').checked == true)
   {   alert("id of checked element is:"+i);
   }
}
```

How can I put the value of **i** here inside the brackets ?

```
{   if (document.getElementById('i').checked == true)
```

Comment: `,getElementById('[' + i + ']')` ??

Comment: `document.getElementById(i)`

Comment: your inputs have ids id="1", id="2" ?

Comment: Well you are looking for the string "i", not the variable

Comment: () are typically called parenthesis, not brackets.

Comment: inside of brackets, I need to put the value of i

Comment: LIKE:   document.getElementById( "1" )  for  i = 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of options

```js
if (document.getElementById(`${i}`).checked == true)
  
  //or

  if (document.getElementById(i.toString()).checked == true)
  
  // or even
  
   if (document.getElementById(i).checked == true)
```

Comment: if (document.getElementById(`${i}`).checked == true)  WORKED, thank you

Comment: Please consider marking my response as answer if it worked for you.